# Resharper: Ctrl-Backspace deletes just one subword of a CamelCaseWord

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

When I have the text:

```
new ResharperFeature
```

And I press *Ctrl-Backspace*, I get:

```
new Resharper
```

And I want:

```
new
```

This issue exists only on my work PC. It must be misconfigured. What is the setting that I can change to get the "normal" behavior?

Note: I verified that this is a R# problem by suspending R#. The problem went away.

Comment: Have you tried disabling R# to eliminate the possibility? That would take 1min :)

Comment: I think the accepted answer here may be your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767934/ctrl-backspace-visual-studio-2010

Comment: fury, good idea ;-) I edited the question. It is R#'s fault.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to **ReSharper > Options > Environment > Editor**, and deselect **Use CamelHumps**

Note that this will also affect **Ctrl+W/Ctrl+Shift+W** ([Extend/Shrink Selection](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#ExtendShrink_Selection)) and **Ctrl+Left/Right**

Comment: This is the solution. Thank god.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Visual Studio 2010. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533093
Hope it will be fixed for VS 2012

Comment: This is a different bug/feature. My problem is that partial words get deleted instead of the whole word.